# How to set bottom padding of the Frontiers of computer science Journal latex template?

Tags: page-breaking, templates, overflow

I am using the template of Frontiers of computer Science Journal to format my research paper. The template can be found in the link below.

https://journal.hep.com.cn/fcs/EN/column/column11258.shtml

It has some problem with bottom padding of the page, I am using this template as it is. You can see in the image below that bottom is of the page is not correctly padded.

[image: LaTeX image]

The code of the template is given below:

```
\documentclass{fcs}
\usepackage{bm}

%% Volumn number
\volumn{ }
%% DOI
\doi{ }
%% Types of papers, can be
%%   RESEARCH~ARTICLE
%%   REVIEW~ARTICLE
%%   EDITORIALS
\articletype{REVIEW~ARTICLE}
%% Copyright notice
\copynote{{\copyright} Higher Education Press and Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg 2012}
%% Time of receive and acceptance
\ratime{Received month dd, yyyy; accepted month dd, yyyy}
%% Email address of the corresponding author
\email{$\times\times\times\times@\times\times\times.\times\times\times$}
%% Title
\title{$\bm{Frontiers~ of~ Computer~ Science}$\\[2mm] Instruction for authors}
%% Authors
\author{Firstname LASTNAME \xff $^{1,2}$}
%% Addresses of authors
\address{{1\quad Higher Education Press, Beijing 100029, China}\\
{2\quad Acadcmic Journal Division, Beijing 100029, China}}

%% Running head
\markboth{Front. Comput. Sci.}{Firstname LASTNAME: please insert running head here}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{14pt}

\begin{abstract}
A short abstract of up to 300 words written in one
paragraph, clearly indicating the object and scope of the paper as
well as the results achieved, should appear on the first page. It
should be written using the abstract environment.
\end{abstract}

\Keywords{Up to 8 words separated by commas.}

\section{Introduction}

\noindent Frontiers of Computer Science is an international
peer-reviewed academic journal sponsored by the Ministry of
Education of China. The journal is jointly published by Higher
Education Press of China and Springer on a bimonthly basis in
English. Online versions are available through both
http://www.springerlink.com/content/11704 and
http://journal.hep.com.cn/fcs.

The journal publishes primarily research article and review article
by following the peer-review system. At least three reviewers are
requested in the relevant study fields, and review feed-back will
usually take about three months.

Manuscripts submitted to this journal must not be under simultaneous
consideration by any other publisher and should not have been
published elsewhere in substantially similar form. No part of a
paper which has been published by Frontiers of Computer Science may
be reproduced or published elsewhere without the written permission
of the publisher.

The content of the manuscript must not include information whose
disclosure will be prejudicial to the national interest. The
authorization license has to be submitted, by the organization the
research is sponsored, in case that any information in the
manuscript is suspicious to be confidential.

The following categories of papers can be submitted to the journal:

\begin{itemize}
\item RESEARCH articles describing original investigations relevant to Computer Science;
\item REVIEW articles giving an in-depth overview of certain topic or a review of one's own work or one
        laboratory or a group of researchers;
\item EDITORIALS providing overview on certain topic written by well known scientists in the field.
\end{itemize}

\section{Manuscript preparation and submission requirements}
\subsection{Manuscript submission}

Authors are encouraged to submit their papers electronically via the
online submission system (http://mc.manuscriptcentral.com/hepfcs).
The web site guides authors stepwise through the creation and
uploading of the various files. When you first submit your paper,
please upload the PDF file. When your paper is accepted, you will be
required to send the original source files. All correspondence,
including the editor's decision and request for revisions, will be
by e-mail. After reviewing process, the manuscript will be finally
judged by one of the editors and the EIC who have the right to
accept or reject a paper.

\subsection{Submission requirements}
\subsubsection{Cover letter}

A covering letter must accompany each submission indicating the
name, address, and telephone number of the author to whom all
correspondence is to be addressed. An affiliation must be supplied
for each author. Authors are also asked to provide the names and
contact information for four potential referees in their cover
letter. However, the journal is not obliged to use the suggested
reviewers. Final selection of reviewers will be determined by the
editors.

\subsubsection{Manuscript for research articles}

Manuscripts should be in a Word or LaTeX format. The following
components are required for a complete manuscript: Title, Author(s),
Author affiliation(s), Abstract, Keywords, Nomenclature (when
needed), Main text, References, Acknowledgements, Appendices, Figure
captions, Tables. There is no formal limit for the length of a
paper, but the editors may recommend condensation when appropriate.



\begin{itemize}
\item Tables
\end{itemize}
Authors should take notice of the limitations set by the size and
layout of the journal. Large tables should be avoided. Reversing
columns and rows will often reduce the dimensions of a table.

If many data are to be presented, an attempt should be made to
divide them over two or more tables.

\begin{itemize}
\item Supply units of measure at the heads of the columns. Abbreviations that are used only in a table
        should be defined in the footnotes to that table.
\item Should always use rows and columns to correlate two variables. Do not embed tables as graphic files,
        document objects, or pictures.
\item Submitted as three-line tables, that is, there are three horizontal lines: one under the legend, one
        under the column heads, and one below the body. Vertical lines are generally not used.
\item Label each table at the top with a Roman numeral followed by the table title. Insert explanatory material
        and footnotes below the table. Designate footnotes using lowercase superscript letters (a, b, c) reading
        horizontally across the table.
\item Unless needed, all the words within the tables should be in lowercases.
\item Must be sequentially numbered and called out in the text as, e.g., Table 1. The table should appear
        after where it is first mentioned in the text.
\end{itemize}

\doublerulesep 0.1pt
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{footnotesize}
\caption{Please write your table caption here} \label{tab:1}
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{1.6cm}p{1.6cm}p{1.5cm}}
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    sample&2/d& 4/d&6/d \\
\noalign{\smallskip} \hline
    blank control& 61.5 & 71.4&68.0 \\
    PLA & 73.2 & 75.6 &65.2 \\
    HA-PLA & 54.4 & 78.6 &62.4 \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{table}




\begin{itemize}
\item Figures
\end{itemize}
Graphs should be practically self-explanatory. Readers should be
able to understand them at a glance. Dimensional drawings and
diagrams should include only the essential details and as little
lettering as possible. They should present more of a picture than a
working drawing. Figure requirements:

1) Size: should be drawn in the size of they virtually appear.

2) Numbering and title: number all figures (graphs, charts,
photographs, and illustrations) in the order of their citation in
the text and cited as, e.g., Fig. 1. Include a title for each
figure (a brief phrase, preferably no longer than 10 to 15 words).
Use (a), (b), (c), (d) to give titles for subfigures if there are
any.

3) Figure quality: should be sharp, noise-free, and of good
contrast. All lettering should be large enough to permit legible
reduction. The figure quality should meet the requirements: 300dpi
for color images; 600dpi for mono images; 72dpi for screen images;
600dpi for line-drawings.

4) Color of figures: unless necessary, better drawn in black and
white for line-drawing; and grayscale for images.

5) Figure file formats and location in manuscript: should be
embedded in word or LaTeX processing documents. When accepted,
original files should be provided in TIFF, EPS or Corel-Draw file
formats. Legends should appear, separate from the figures
themselves, where the figures should be located within the paper.

6) Maps: please use the authorized maps as the basis for map figure
drawing. (Like maps published by China Map Press, and the like.) Any
maps drawn without an authorized basis have to be submitted with the
certificate from the Surveying and Mapping management. All the maps
should follow the publishing requirements released by the
Government.

7) Unless needed, all the words within the figures should be in
lowercases. There is one example:



\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\includegraphics{FCS-1}
\caption{How C changes with (a) $p$; (b) $p_{t}$}\label{Fig049}
\end{figure}


\begin{itemize}
\item Formulae and equations
\end{itemize}
The requirement for formulae and equations are:

1) Formulae should be typewritten whenever possible.

2) It is extremely important that all mathematical symbols and
letters used are identified and listed and that the required style
of appearance of such symbols is clearly indicated, e.g., bold face,
italics, script, outline, etc.

3) Subscripts and superscripts should be set off clearly.

4) Identify in the margin any symbols that might be confused with
similar symbols.

5) The words Equation or Equations should appear in full at the
beginning of sentences but be abbreviated to Eq. or Eqs. elsewhere.

6) A nomenclature can be included (with the use of = signs) after
the abstract if there is a significant number of symbols in the
paper.

7) Equations should be located separately from other lines. Authors
are encouraged to place them in two-column format, unless it is
necessary to place them in one-column.

For example:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1} H=-\frac{1}{2}\Delta \sigma _\infty +\sum\limits_k
{\omega _k b_k^\dag b_k } +\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_k {g_k (b_k^ +b_k
)\sigma _z } ,
\end{equation}
\begin{itemize}
\item Definition, example, theorem, proof, etc
\end{itemize}
Please do not use italic in these parts. For example:

\textbf{Example 1}~~~We take the data set 1{\ldots}

\begin{itemize}
\item Abbreviations
\end{itemize}
Do not use abbreviations in the title or abstract and limit their
use in the text. Expand all abbreviations at first mention in the
text.

\begin{itemize}
\item Footnotes
\end{itemize}
Footnotes should only be used if absolutely essential. In most cases
it will be possible to incorporate the information in normal text.
If used, they should be indicated by superscript characters (e.g.,
1), 2), . . .)\footnote{Footnote information
1}, and kept as short as possible.

\begin{itemize}
\item Citations and references
\end{itemize}
In-text citations must agree with the references in either numbering
or names and year. The references should be presented completely and
without mistakes, and should be the original publication. We use the
citation-sequence system, that is to number the citations according
to sequence of their first appearance. Journal names should be
spelled out in full. Examples are given in \cite{KargerD,Mastroianni,SchlessingerD,ZhugeH}.

\begin{itemize}
\item Others
\end{itemize}
The digital object identifier (DOI) may be used to cite and link to
electronic documents. Consisting of a unique alpha-numeric character
string which is assigned to a document by the publisher upon the
initial electronic publication, DOI is an ideal medium for citing a
document, particularly "Articles in press" because they have not yet
received their full bibliographic information. The correct format
for citing a DOI is shown as follows (example taken from a document
in the Communications in Nonlinear Science and Numerical
Simulation): doi:10.1016/j.cnsns.2007.05.034

\subsection{Manuscript for review articles}

Reviews give a general overview of a particular field, providing the
reader with an appreciation of the importance of the work,
historical context, a summary of recent developments, and a starting
point in the specialist literature. Manuscripts should be between 4
000 and 8 000 words in length, divided into appropriate sections,
such as introduction (motivation and history remarks); outline;
basic concepts, examples and results; comments on the relevance of
the results, relations to other results and applications; open
problems; critical review of the relevant literature; comprehensive
bibliography. In addition to undergoing the same rigorous level of
technical peer-review as Research papers, Review articles will be
critiqued based on the general impact of the field being reviewed,
the relevance of the field to experimental mechanics, preexisting
reviews of the field, and acknowledgement of the contributing author
as a dominant figure in the field. Therefore, it is strongly
recommended that authors interested in submitting a Review article
correspond with the Editor prior to submission. General formatting
text, illustrations, and references are the same as outlined for
research papers.

\section{Notification}

\noindent The corresponding author will be notified by the editors
of the acceptance of article and invited to supply an electronic
version of the accepted text, if this is not already available.

\section{Copyright transfer}

\noindent No article can be published unless accompanied by a signed
copyright transfer statement, which ensures a transfer of copyright
from author to publisher. A copy of the copyright transfer statement
to be used will be provided with the letter of acceptance of the
manuscript. Authors are asked to scan and return by email the signed
statement to the editorial office of Frontiers of Computer Science.

\section{Proofreading and production}

\noindent Proofs will be sent to the author and should be returned
within 5 days of receipt. Authors should clarify any questions of
the proof in a query file. No new materials shall be inserted at the
time of proofreading. Please note that authors are urged to check
their proofs carefully before return one all-inclusive e-mail or
fax, since subsequent additional corrections will not be possible.

\section{Author enquiries}

\noindent For submission inquiries, tracking articles and any
information please contact the Frontiers of Computer Science office
in Higher Education Press. All correspondence for the journal should
be sent to the managing editor (FCS@pub.hep.cn). Please be sure to
include the manuscript dispatch number in all correspondences.



\section{Author benefits}

\noindent The articles enjoy a fast peer-review and production
workflow and will be published more quickly with the online first
publishing on the basis of individual articles. The submitted
manuscripts will get polished in language by highly qualified
editors before typeset if necessary.

\Acknowledgements{The ``Acknowledgement section'' is the general
term for the list of contributions, credits, and other information
included at the end of the text of a manuscript but before the
references. Conflicts of interest and financial disclosures must be
listed in this section. Authors should obtain written permission to
include the names of individuals in the Acknowledgement section.}


\section*{Appendixes~(if needed)}

Appendix A


\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Mastroianni} Verta O. Mastroianni C, Talia D. A super-peer model for resource
discovery services in large-scale grids. Future Generation Computer
Systems, 2005, 21(8): 1235--1248

\bibitem{ZhugeH} Zhuge H. The Knowledge Grid. Singapore: World Scientific Publishing Co.,
2004

\bibitem{SchlessingerD}
Schlessinger D. Schaechter M. Bacterial toxins. In: Schaechter M,
Medoff G, Eisenstein BI, eds. Mechanisms of microbial disease. 2nd
ed. Baltimore: Williams and Wilkins, 1993, 162--175

\bibitem{KargerD}
Karger D. Ruhl M. Simple efficient load balancing algorithms for
peer-to-peer systems. In: Proceedings of Sixteenth Annual ACM
Symposium on Parallelism in Algorithm and Architectures. 2004,
36--40
\end{thebibliography}

%% \Biography{#1}{#2}
%% #1 is the file name of photo,
%% #2 is author's biography
\Biography{fcs-2}{Please provide each author's biography here with no
more than 120 words. The photo can be informal. Our journal prefers
to exhibit an encouraging atmosphere. Please use a one that best
suits our journal.}

%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%\bibliography{oo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the class file provided by `Frontiers`, then why not you approach them

Comment: Their `fcl.cls` file loads article class with `a4paper` as one of the options but then sets `paperheight` to `277truemm`, which is 2cm shorten then standard A4. Changing this to `297truemm` seems to solve it but I wonder why `277` was there in the first place.

Comment: But I would definitely consult with them and clarify this before making any changes in this file. It's not been edited since 2014!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I solved it by adding the following code in the fcs.cls file (add it where all the other `\RequirePackage` are placed):

```
\RequirePackage[a5paper]{geometry}
```

Alternatively, I think it could be possible to modify the text height in the fcs.cls file:

```
\setlength{\textheight}{235truemm}
```

By finding the above line and replacing 235truemm with something smaller (e.g., 205truemm), it should be possible to fit the text on the page.

Important notice: I do not know if the paper complies with the journal's guidelines after modifying the fcs.cls file.